# Isssues upgrading to civiCRM 5.52

Tags: upgrade

I am ready to upgrade to version 5.52.
Has anyone run into any problems upgrading to version 5.52?

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of problems you're expecting? Youldn't it be better to search for them?

Answer (score 1):

5.53 hasn't been released yet and is beta right now, but it's available and you're welcome to test it: https://download.civicrm.org/latest.

If you're looking for how many people are running a version, there are some stats here: http://stats.civicrm.org/?tab=technology. They aren't perfect, and don't show test sites, but give you some idea.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped, I meant 5.52 that was released August 3, 2022